# How to get Device Id from adb

Tags: android, admob

Could you tell me how to get device Id  from adb command?

I tried:
adb logcat > file.txt
but I can't find it. ( I search by 'device id', 'test', 'ads' and few other)

I need it this ID to put my device to TEst devices list because I need to test Ads from AdMob.

Thanks

Comment: This is Device ID? Number after 'List of devices attached'.  I thought it's larger:

Comment: what you needed exactly?

Comment: I need Device ID of my phone, because I have to put it in Test Devices. I need to test ads from AdMob

Comment: List of devices attached 
ZX1B34W49D      device    it shows like this.

Comment: This is example device id to test ads from ADMob: 540b119b9a7349adf54afb0ac8807080 Its larger than I got from: ads devices, but I try it.

Comment: Maybe that help: console.developers.google.com/project/469460945175/apiui/apis/library?authuser=0